# How to use jLinq in IBM Worklight Application

Tags: json, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to use the `jLinq.js` library [here](http://jlinq.codeplex.com/) in my application. I copied the `.js` file into `js` folder of my project and created a database.js file in wich i have data.

`database.js` is something like this:

```
var database = [
{"key": "value1"},
{"key": "value2"}
];
```

and in my `ApplicationName.js` file i have this:

```
function wlCommonInit(){

 $("#button").bind("click",function(){
    var tag = "";
    jLinq.from(database)
    .select(function(data){           
       tag += "<p>"+data.key+"</p>";
    });
    $("#mydiv").append(tag);
 });

}

// the result is
// <p>value1</p>
// <p>value2</p>
```

but i get the error `Can't find variable: jlinq`. I have included the `jLinq.js` in `ApplicationName.html` and also `database.js`.

EDIT: changed the `ApplicationName.js` code and it works right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it possibly just be a typo? The 'L' isn't capitalized in your code.

Change

```
jlinq.from(database)
```

to

```
jLinq.from(database)
```

Comment: it works! but i get `undefined` value. i'll try to resolve also this. Thanks